# NSArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have this code, but when I log the mediaDictionaryArray, I get null. Does the receiver array have to be initialized with a value first or can I add objects to an empty array? Does [NSArray array] vs. [[NSArray alloc]init] have anything to do with it?

Adding dictionary from API call that happens i times. Asynch call will return the dictionary - can't be sure if NSMutableArray will work in catchJSONArray since asynch nature of call will make the array of indeterminate size which will make it hard to use later on.

Updated with relevant bit.

```
    for (int i = 0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSString *getString = array[i];
    NSLog(@"getstring %@", getString);
    [client GET:getString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
            if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    _locationMediaArray = (NSArray*)responseObject[@"data"];
                    [self catchJSONArray:_locationMediaArray];
```

then here is method with the array issue

```
 -(void)catchJSONArray:(NSArray*)array{  

NSArray *catchJSONArray = [NSArray array];

_mediaDictionaryArray = [catchJSONArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array];

NSLog(@"mediaDictionaryArray %@", _mediaDictionaryArray);
```

}

Comment: I don't get it.  Your `catchJSONArray` method creates an empty array, merges that with the parameter array, and sets your property to the merged array.  That merged array will always be the parameter array, so you might as well just set the property with the parameter directly, unless you have some reason for wanting a copy vs the original (in which case you can simply use `copy`).

Comment: @HotLicks Hey Hot Licks, the problem is the API call only returns one dictionary at a time. I want to fill up an array with the dictionaries returned from the API call when it's done iterating through the API calls, which is hard since it's asynch and I don't know when that block will have completed. The code above was an attempt at something which obviously did not work.

Comment: There are a dozen different ways to handle that -- lock the array while updating, do `performSelectorOnMainThread`, etc.  But fundamental to any of them is to actually look at the documentation and understand what a given method is doing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP does not understand the basics of what he'd trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray returns a **new** array containing your objects, as an NSArray can not be changed once created.
If you want to change an existing array, you should be using an NSMutableArray.

Comment: So, to use this method, I'd have to alloc and init an array to store the copy?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs Is what you're trying to do is adding objects to an existing array? If so, your _mediaDictionaryArray should be of class NSMutableArray, then you can add objects to it by using the method  addObjectsFromArray:

Comment: basically, I have a for loop that creates objects and I want them to update my array as they come in from an asynchronous block. I don't want to use a mutable array since I won't know how many items it has when I use it later in the code

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs I'm not sure if I got you correctly, but you do can check how many items the array has simply by calling the - [NSArray count].

Comment: right, that's why I can't use NSMutableArray since count may not be accurate at the time I run it.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs I don't understand the situation that much. can you edit your original post with some blocks of code so I could be more helpful?

Comment: "I can't use NSMutableArray since count may not be accurate at the time I run it."  You know, you can query the size of an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

The best way you could do this is:

```
_mediaDictionaryArray=[NSArray arrayWithArray:otherArray];
```

That will create a new array with the contents of otherArray and assign it to _mediaDictionary.

Comment: Or one could simply do `[otherArray copy]`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to alloc init your array just pass the refrence of your other array. If 
_mediaDictionaryArray is mutable array then use below:-

```
  _mediaDictionaryArray=[array mutableCopy];
```

If it is non mutable array then use below

```
 _mediaDictionaryArray=[array copy];
```